# How to get number of online users in your app?

Tags: ios, game-center, icloud

I'm creating game in which I need to show how many users are online. There can be timeout of 5 minutes for example. Is there any API for iCloud or Game Center to get number of user which are online?

Comment: You can get the online user count by using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: @Ushan87 - can I get number then and show in the app?

Comment: Oh sorry missed that bit of your question. my bad. and no you cannot show the online users count using Google Analytics.

Comment: You cannot do it using GameCenter, you will have to save the amount of playing users at your own server.

Comment: There's nothing remotely similar to this in iCloud.